# JSON does not show new line formatting

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have an array with `<br />` HTML tag:

```
$allresult[$key]['title'] = 'Event Type : '.$val['type'].'<br />Start Date : '.$val['startdate'].'<br /> End Date : '.$val['enddate'].'<br /> Office : '.$val['office'].'<br /> Client : '.$val['client'].'<br /> Contact : '.$val['contact'].'<br><br>';
$eventresult['result'] = $allresult; 
echo json_encode($eventresult);
```

It does not show output in formated html. For example it should show some thing like that. Each entity should come in Each line.

```
Event Type : Medical
Start Date : 20-03-2017
End Date : 30-03-2017
Traveller : Mike Jakson
Destination : New Delhi/India
```

Mean New line html tag is not working. Currently the output is showing everything in one line. Please suggest, how to achieve the desired output.

Comment: do you run in web browser frontend

Comment: why are you inserting html in json?? The output you have given in not json

Comment: json will never show new line.

Comment: Do something like this:-https://eval.in/769356

Answer (score 0):

Use `"\n"` instead of `'<br/>'`. Inside double quotes.

Comment: We are running it into web browser using codeignitor. The output is showing once we do mouse over. We try with "\n" instead of '<br />' tag. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your didn't send correct html headers to your browser and your text is recognized as plain/text. This works for me perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $allresult[$key]['title'] = 'Event Type : '.$val['type'].'<br />Start Date : '.$val['startdate'].'<br /> End Date : '.$val['enddate'].'<br /> Office : '.$val['office'].'<br /> Client : '.$val['client'].'<br /> Contact : '.$val['contact'].'<br><br>';
        $eventresult['result'] = $allresult; 
        echo json_encode($eventresult);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, if your page is not html content, you could replace 
 tags into \r\n sequence.